# ASP MVC4: A issue when manipulating variable value in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Thanks everyone's effort of helping me out, basically I'm facing a problem in controller below, just make it simple and easy:

```
   Controller C{

       public list<model> a;
       //used in action A, if it's a searched list, then don't initialize;
       public bool searched = false;


       public ActionResult A(){
          if(searched){
             ViewBag.a = a;
          }else
          //initial the list
          a = db.model.where();
          .....
          return view()
       }

       //return a result list when people search by keywords
       public ActionResult B(string str){
          a = db.model.where(d=> d.id = str);
          search = true;
       }

    }
```

But, it turned out that the value of both a and researched never changed after B called

Did I miss some critical knowledge in .NET MVC?

Any related articles are very welcomed

Thanks

Comment: Is it a quiz of something? If you have this code, why wouldn't you try it first?

Comment: Nope it's my actual page, when I sent back my request, it seems all the TempData was gone, and the static member in controller class are re-initialized,  sorry I'm just a beginner in MVC, but is there a way to keep a value that has page-life?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just using a model?

Comment: Than it's better start from the problem that you experience, rather than solution. In MVC the is no page life like it was in Asp.net. The thing is, if you want to store value during 1 request - use ViewBag, ViewDate (same thing), 2 requests - TempData (usually for validation), longer - Session. @adrian-wrang have good explanation. Otherwise, you may think of passing values as action parameters.

Comment: Thank you @Dima, to make more clear I rewrote my content, please see above and be free to tell me if there are some critical knowledge I missed about MVC

Answer (score 4):

You should use `TempData` to keep your value after redirect. It is exactly TempData was designed for.
In your example it will be:

```
Controller C{

       public ActionResult A(){
          TempData["str"] = "this is A";
          return RedirectToActionB()
       }
       public ActionResult B(){
          TempData["str"] += "This is B";
          return View()
       }

    }
```

Comment: that's a very good point, but on the view when I press a button and the request sent back into the controller, all the TempData variables will disappear? Or they just keep all the previous values?

Comment: Used that, and editted the problem, do you think I made it wrong way this time? @Pavel Kutakov

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're asking because it's not giving the result you expect, rather than because you want someone to try it for you. The easy answer (assuming you meant "On the B's View Page") is "This is B".

A `RedirectToAction` will send a redirection to the browser, which initiates a new request to the server. Unfortunately a `ViewBag`'s life is only for a single request, so it will no longer be populated when action B runs.

You will need to find another way to pass the data; for example, in a cookie or within the `Session` object.

Comment: Hi @Adrian Wragg, thanks and that's exactly what I'm asking, in your opinion, which is best way to pass values from one action to another(Caz I'm thinking of using static variables, will it occupy lots of resources?)

Comment: Without knowing your full use case, it's difficult to give 100% accurate advice. I tend towards the Session, but try and keep the amount of data stored there to a minimum; for example, I may serialise the data into storage and then pass around a UID that allows it to be retrieved later.

Comment: Just rewrote the content again, thank you for helping me and please be free to point out if I miss some important knowledge in MVC framework

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
return RedirectToActionB()
```

Try:

```
return B();
```

You'll save a redundant Http request as well.

Comment: is there a way to keep a value in controller in page-life-time? (I tried static member but didn't work)

Comment: @cadrell0, Generally, you're right since the OP explicitly mentioned redirection. still, i'm suggesting doing it without redirection (and there are other ways in modern browsers to change the URL / history state).

Comment: @LifeScript, what do you mean by 'page-life-time'? and `static` values in controller are almost never a good option.

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net mvc controller doesn't keep it's fields/properties during requests: you'll have new instance of `C` on each web request. This means that you cannot expect `a` and `searched` fields to keep their state after action B completion.

You may use ViewBag(ViewData) to pass values between controller and view during request.
You may use TempData to store values during 2 requests, it's usually being used in PRG pattern    for example.
You may use Session to keep your values while client's session is alive.
You may pass values between requests using hidden inputs on your page, query parameters, or less obvious things like HttpHeaders and others.

If you want to pass values between actions A and B, you may use TempData or Session is collection isn't big (it'll be stored in encrypted cookie which size cannot exceed 4k as far as I remember).
There is an another option which may be useful. You may store your collection in client's [localstorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) if it's ok in your case.